# Ошибка update mysql

Tags: python

Никак не пойму где ошибка в коде при обновлении записи

```
Ошибка:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 238, in execute
    query = query % args
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Учеба/Диплом/parsers/smartphone/kimovil.py", line 921, in <module>
    start_parsing_phones()
  File "D:/Учеба/Диплом/parsers/smartphone/kimovil.py", line 874, in start_parsing_phones
    for _ in executor.map(parsing_phone, urls_phone):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 586, in result_iterator
    yield fs.pop().result()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 432, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 56, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "D:/Учеба/Диплом/parsers/smartphone/kimovil.py", line 861, in parsing_phone
    product_id = request_db(sql, data)
  File "D:/Учеба/Диплом/parsers/smartphone/kimovil.py", line 89, in request_db
    cursor.executemany(sql, data)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 283, in executemany
    self.rowcount = sum(self.execute(query, arg) for arg in args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 283, in <genexpr>
    self.rowcount = sum(self.execute(query, arg) for arg in args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 240, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, ProgrammingError, str(m))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 52, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass(errorvalue)
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Код:

```
def request_db(sql,data):
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="project")
    conn.set_character_set('utf8')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SET NAMES utf8;')
    cursor.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;')
    cursor.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')
    conn.autocommit(True)
    cursor.executemany(sql, data)
    last_row_id= cursor.lastrowid
    conn.close()
    return last_row_id

sql = """UPDATE product SET name = %s, product_group = %s, name_alternative = %s,  image_path = %s, brand = %s, represented = %s, state = %s, width = %s, height = %s, thickness = %s, ratio_side = %s, weight = %s, surface_use = %s, certificate_resistance = %s, diagonal = %s, display_type = %s, display_s = %s, btype = %s, count_pixels_x = %s,  count_pixels_y = %s,  density_pixels = %s,  display_capacitive = %s,  multitouch = %s,  display_25d_surved_glass = %s,  display_brightness = %s,  display_protective_glass = %s,  forcetouch = %s,  display_ogs = %s,  display_scratch_resistance = %s,  display_oleophobic_lipophobic_coating = %s,  display_ltps = %s,  display_zero_air_gap = %s,  display_triluminos = %s,  display_xReality = %s,  display_contrast_ratio = %s, always_on_display = %s, 
                            processor_model = %s, processor_CPU = %s, processor_count_core = %s,  processor_frequency = %s,  processor_64_bits = %s,  graphics_GPU = %s,  ram = %s,  antutu = %s,  rom = %s,  rom_expandable = %s,  fingerprint = %s,  fingerprint_location = %s,  accelerometer = %s,  compas = %s,  sensor_gravity = %s,  gyroscope = %s,  sensor_hall = %s,  magnetometer = %s,  pedometer = %s,  sensor_light = %s,  sensor_proximity = %s,  led_notification = %s,  camera_resolution = %s,  camera_sensor = %s,  camera_sensor_type = %s,  camera_opening = %s,  video_4K = %s, camera_autofocus = %s,  camera_serial_shooting = %s, camera_digital_zoom = %s,  camera_exposure_ompensation = %s, camera_face_detection = %s,  camera_geographic_tags = %s,  camera_hdr_shooting = %s, 
                            camera_setting_ISO = %s,  camera_manual_focus = %s,  camera_optical_stabilization = %s,  camera_panoramic_shooting = %s,  camera_RAW = %s,  camera_scene_mode = %s,  camera_selftimer = %s,  camera_touch_focus = %s,  camera_settings_balance_white = %s,  camera_video_slow_motion = %s,  camera_video_slow_motion_fps = %s,  camera_video_optical_stabilization = %s,  camera_frontal_resolution = %s,  net_4G = %s,  net_4G_frequency = %s, net_3G_frequency = %s,  net_2G_frequency = %s,  sim_card_count = %s,  sim_card_modework = %s,  sim_card_type = %s,  WIFI_support_standart = %s,  WIFI_mode_dualBand = %s,  WIFI_Direct = %s,  WIFI_Display = %s,  WIFI_Hotspot = %s,  WIFI_MiMO = %s,  bluetooth_version = %s,  bluetooth_LE = %s, 
                            bluetooth_mode_A2DP = %s,  bluetooth_mode_AVRCP = %s,  bluetooth_mode_GAP = %s,  bluetooth_mode_GAVDP = %s,  bluetooth_mode_HDP = %s, bluetooth_mode_HFP = %s,  bluetooth_mode_HID = %s,  bluetooth_mode_HSP = %s,  bluetooth_mode_MAP = %s,  bluetooth_mode_OPP = %s,  bluetooth_mode_PAN = %s,  bluetooth_mode_PBAP_PAB = %s,  bluetooth_mode_SPP = %s,  satellite_nafigation_AGPS = %s,  satellite_nafigation_Beidou = %s,  satellite_nafigation_Glonass = %s,  satellite_nafigation_GPS = %s,  satellite_nafigation_Galileo = %s,  usb_charging = %s,  usb_host = %s,  usb_mass_charger = %s,  usb_OTG = %s,  usb_type_C = %s,  audio_jack = %s,  FM_Radio = %s,  computer_synchronization = %s,  DLNA = %s,  infrared_port = %s,  NFS = %s,  OTA_synchronization = %s, 
                            tethering = %s,  VoLTE = %s,  battery_capacity = %s,  battery_type = %s,  battery_fast_charging = %s,  battery_withdral = %s,  operation_system  = %s  where url = %s"""
data = [(name, product_group,name_alternative, image_path, brand, represented, state, width, height, thickness, ratio_side, weight,
                 surface_use, certificate_resistance, diagonal, display_type, display_subtype, count_pixels_x, count_pixels_y, density_pixels,
                 display_capacitive, multitouch, display_25d_surved_glass, display_brightness, display_protective_glass, forcetouch, display_ogs,
                 display_scratch_resistance, display_oleophobic_lipophobic_coating, display_ltps, display_zero_air_gap, display_triluminos,
                 display_xReality, display_contrast_ratio, always_on_display,
                 processor_model, processor_CPU, processor_count_core, processor_frequency, processor_64_bits, graphics_GPU, ram, antutu, rom,
                 rom_expandable, fingerprint, fingerprint_location, accelerometer, compas, sensor_gravity, gyroscope, sensor_hall, magnetometer,
                 pedometer, sensor_light, sensor_proximity, led_notification, camera_resolution, camera_sensor, camera_sensor_type, camera_opening,
                 video_4K, camera_autofocus, camera_serial_shooting, camera_digital_zoom, camera_exposure_ompensation, camera_face_detection,
                 camera_geographic_tags, camera_hdr_shooting,
                 camera_setting_ISO, camera_manual_focus, camera_optical_stabilization, camera_panoramic_shooting, camera_RAW, camera_scene_mode,
                 camera_selftimer, camera_touch_focus, camera_settings_balance_white, camera_video_slow_motion, camera_video_slow_motion_fps,
                 camera_video_optical_stabilization, camera_frontal_resolution, net_4G, net_4G_frequency, net_3G_frequency, net_2G_frequency,
                 sim_card_count, sim_card_modework, sim_card_type, WIFI_support_standart, WIFI_mode_dualBand, WIFI_Direct, WIFI_Display, WIFI_Hotspot,
                 WIFI_MiMO, bluetooth_version, bluetooth_LE,
                 bluetooth_mode_A2DP, bluetooth_mode_AVRCP, bluetooth_mode_GAP, bluetooth_mode_GAVDP, bluetooth_mode_HDP, bluetooth_mode_HFP,
                 bluetooth_mode_HID, bluetooth_mode_HSP, bluetooth_mode_MAP, bluetooth_mode_OPP, bluetooth_mode_PAN, bluetooth_mode_PBAP_PAB,
                 bluetooth_mode_SPP, satellite_nafigation_AGPS, satellite_nafigation_Beidou, satellite_nafigation_Glonass, satellite_nafigation_GPS,
                 satellite_nafigation_Galileo, usb_charging, usb_host, usb_mass_charger, usb_OTG, usb_type_C, audio_jack, FM_Radio,
                 computer_synchronization, DLNA, infrared_port, NFS, OTA_synchronization,
                 tethering, VoLTE, battery_capacity, battery_type, battery_fast_charging, battery_withdral, operation_system, url)]
        product_id = request_db(sql, data)
```

Comment: Считай аргументы, загибая пальцы - должно потребоваться 136 пальцев. Потом то же, но для значений - хватит всего 135 пальцев. А дальше думай сам...PS. Проблема - не в MySQL, а в арифметике, лишний тег удалён.

Comment: Код — ужас, конечно, вам бы все эти переменные в единый словарь запихнуть

Comment: @adreymal, ты извини,я в программировании новичок, можешь на примере показать

Comment: @Akino, спасибо, ошибку нашел

Comment: чтобы легче отлаживать было, используйте именованные параметры (`name = %(name)s, product_group = %(product_group)s,...`) и передавайте словарь¶ В сторону: если вы на таких ошибках (*"not enough arguments for format string"*) застреваете, то стоит самые самые основы языка изучить, чтобы сэкономить время на отладке. Стоит знать что такое [нормальная форма](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0) и не использовать таблицы в денормализованном виде, если вы твёрдо не уверены зачем в вашем случае это надо.

Comment: @jfs Что мы имеете про денормализованный вид? вы имеете ввиду, что должны у каждой ячейки должна быть определена сущность, в которой будут прописаны все возможные значения и ссылаться по Id?

Comment: @danilshik: про нормальные формы можно целые книги писать. Если у вас вопрос нужно ли и как конкретно нормализовывать представленную таблицу, то отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос задайте (или подождите пока конкретная проблема появится)